# Loading current time into mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a query which can enter data into mysql database. However,i would like to have the time of an entry entered as well and that entered time should correspond to server time.I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS   below is the code i am using to enter data into the table(it is embedded in a script)

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql --local-infile database -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE A.txt INTO TABLE TABLEA columns terminated by '|'"
```

I have created the table to have 3 columns with one for the time with datatype labled as timestamp. How can i edit my code so that it can also insert  the local time. I am using a LAMP stack.  To clarify further, if my table is populated like

```
> ip                                    mac                       time
> 10.0.0.97                        00 14 2A 2F 72 FE          2012-09-09 23:11:05
```

and my textfile contains the data

```
10.0.0.97|00 14 2A 2F 72 FF
 10.0.0.98|00 21 33 RT W3 TT
```

and i run the script now, i would expect it to appear in the database as

```
> ip                                      mac                        
> time
> 10.0.0.97                           00 14 2A 2F 72 FE           2012-09-09 23:11:05
> 10.0.0.97                           00 14 2A 2F 72 FF           2013-18-09 16:11:11
> 10.0.0.98                           00 21 33 RT W3 TT           2013-18-09 16:11:11
```

Comment: If I understand you corecctly I would suggest to use the `NOW()` function. it takes the current `DATETIME` from the server.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but considering that 2 columns are being inserted from the text file, and the 3rd has to be that function, how can it be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you do the LOAD INFILE:

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql 
-e "update database.TABLEA set `time`=now() where `time` IS NULL or `time` = '';"
```

will change TABLEA and set `time` for all records to now() where `time` IS NULL or where `time` is empty (since you do not suply the time stamp with the file this will only alter the new records.

Add a "where" if you need to change less records. Or something like "where `time` IS NULL" if the field is NULL or the actual key the records in the text file have.

2 other methods:

1. Of course you can also provide the timestamp by adding it into the text file you upload.
2. You can also edit the table itself and add [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) as default to ONE(!) column in the table.

By the way: please do not provide the password with this method. It will be shown in your processes list thus viewable for all. More about this can be found in the [official MySQL manual 6.1.2.1. End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html)

Comment: i have put in some edit to clarify on where i am confused

Comment: Hey I was not done editing ;) LOL see the 3rd option; I believe that might be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Thank you, i just made a script of your solution and set it as a cron job